# Want to disable the button for 30 second after the user clicks on it and then enable it automatically in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, authentication, flutter-web, one-time-password

I am working on a login system, where i authenticate user by OTP ,Here i want to disable the **Resend OTP** button for 30 seconds every time the user clicks it and show the time remaining

Comment: Did you check AbsorbPointer, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZITnba-HSY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to have a live counter for showing the user the seconds past you should use stream builder

```
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: _timerStream.stream,
              builder: (BuildContext ctx,
                  AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                return SizedBox(
                  width: 300,
                  height: 30,
                  child:RaisedButton(
                  textColor: Theme.of(context)
                      .accentColor,
                  child: Center(
                      child:
                      snapshot.data == 0 ?
                      Text('send code again')
                          : Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(' button will be enable after ${snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data.toString() : 30} seconds '),
                        ],)
                  ),
                  onPressed: snapshot.data == 0 ? () {
                    // your sending code method

                    _timerStream.sink.add(30);
                    activeCounter();
                  } : null,
                )
                );
              },
            )
```

you can find complete code on dartpad.dev with this [link](https://dartpad.dev/23c25b17a8d663ea8c01b18eae38b2ab)

Comment: thanks for the dartPad. People are awesome

Comment: Take a bit more time to implement but definitely a superior solution.

Answer (score 2):

Declare boolean onPressedValue variable with true,
Add Condition in onPressed Parameter.

```
bool onPressedValue=true;

RaisedButton(
  child: Text('OTP'),
  onPressed: onPressedValue==true?(){
  setState((){
  onPressedValue=false;

  });
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 30),(){
      setState((){
        onPressedValue=true;
      });
    });

}:null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

> Declare a variable call like this globally

```
bool shouldButtonEnabled=true;
```

then on click of send OTP button call this method while you other stuff like sending OTP call this method after it

```
  _disabledButton(){
    shouldButtonEnabled=false;
    Timer(
        Duration(seconds: 30),
            () => shouldButtonEnabled=true);
  }
```

and when check this bool on resend OTP button like this

```
 onPressed: () {
            if(shouldButtonEnabled){
              //do your work here
            }
    }
```